# create zip from file list (including path folders)

Tags: java, spring, zip

I have an application where I can currently zip a list of selected files i.e:

- /baseDir/folder_a/file_a.txt
- /baseDir/folder_b/folder_c/file_b.txt (EXCLUDE)
- /baseDir/folder_b/folder_d/file_c.txt

At the moment I can create a zip file containing all the files. However, the folder structure ist not included, so my zip looks like this:

- /zipFolder/file_a.txt
- /zipFolder/file_c.txt

Since I don't want to zip all files in a folder but only selected one, I have a hard time. Can someone give me hint on how to add the files so it would look like this:

- /zipFolder/folder_a/file_a.txt
- /zipFolder/folder_b/folder_d/file_c.txt

Here is my code:

```
public static byte[] zip(List<File> listFiles) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

    for (File file : listFiles) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            zipDirectory(file, file.getName(), zipOutputStream);
        } else {
            zipFile(file, zipOutputStream);
        }
    }
    zipOutputStream.flush();
    zipOutputStream.close();

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}


private static void zipDirectory(File folder, String parentFolder, ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
            continue;
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            zipDirectory(file, parentFolder + "/" + file.getName(), zos);
            continue;
        }
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(parentFolder + "/" + file.getName()));
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        long bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = bis.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            zos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
            bytesRead += read;
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        bis.close();
    }
}

private static void zipFile(File file, ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    long bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = bis.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
        zos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        bytesRead += read;
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
    bis.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, created archive keeps forlders structure. What is the problem?

Comment: Hm thats weird. When I try my code I don't have the folders structure. I need to add only the relative path without baseDir.